# How to test if transitionProperty (et. al.) takes vendor-prefixed style property names or normalized ones?

Tags: javascript, css, html, vendor-prefix

Here is an excerpt of JS code which sets CSS:

```
function hyphen_style(style) {
    return style.replace(/([A-Z])/g, function(str,m1){ return '-' + m1.toLowerCase(); }).replace(/^ms-/,'-ms-');
}


var css = "#debug_element_highlighter_container * {"+
hyphen_style(Modernizr.prefixed('transitionDuration')) + ": 2s, 2s;" + 
hyphen_style(Modernizr.prefixed('transitionProperty')) + ": transform, opacity;" + 

... 

// append a style tag to head 
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var style = document.createElement("style");
style.type = "text/css";
if (style.styleSheet){
    style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
} else {
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
}
```

Now this does work but I do recall that not a long time ago I had browsers refusing to cooperate without setting the `transitionProperty` using the vendor-prefixed version of the `transform` style property, i.e. the CSS would need to read `-webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;` for the browser to behave the way that I want.

Clearly that should still work today with the browsers that also support `-webkit-transition-property: transform, opacity;`, but we can see that there are four different combination possibilities for whether or not to vendor-prefix either the style name or the style properties set on those styles. It is not unimaginable that at some point in the future some webkit browser would all of a sudden stop checking against `-webkit-` prefixes.

Modernizr (and Modernizr docs) provides us with primitives (`prefixed()` and such) for transformation between them but it's not clear to me how to go about robustly testing if the styles after the fashion of `transitionProperty` require setting the prefixed style property names or not. It is quite straightforward to test the styles themselves to see if they need to be prefixed, by simply assigning the non-prefixed one and seeing if it "takes". But I'm less certain that this same approach will work for the special case of specifying style property names.

Of course, I can just do the hyper-portable overkill approach which is to set all four combinations of CSS declarations whenever this sort of situation comes up, that would leave no room for a browser to find something disagreeable with if it supports any of the styles.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know enough about your application to know if this would work for you, but sites such as http://prefixr.com/ offer an API you can run CSS through that will add any vendor prefixes to your CSS if they are required.

Comment: Thanks, I think prefixr would be a helpful tool for me to use.